# OneToMany Doctrine Symfony 4 как удалить все Many из One?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

У меня имеется объект User, он может писать статьи. Но если мне, как админу, статья не понравилась, то я одной кнопкой удаляю все его статьи.

One: User
Many: Статьи

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать?

Comment: Что значит реализовать? Установить требуемую проперть Юзера в пустую коллекцию.

Answer (score 0):

Пример удаления по пользовательскому id

```
$qb = (здесь объект entityManager)->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete(Article::class, 'article')
     ->where('article.userId = :userId')
     ->setParameter(':userId', $userId)
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```